# Creating a Forms Authentication Rule

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am using Google search appliance and encountered an issue while trying to crawl forms based site. Once I add required fields to create a "new forms authentication" rule, I get a forms authentication login wizard where I enter my credentials. However, I am unable to proceed further as I get a JavaScript error (_doPostBack method ) within the wizard while trying to login. Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

The login button is out-of-the box aspx.net button. So no manipulation is done. Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off javascript. The GSA only needs to know about the communication between client and server. If your login-form doesn't work without javascript enabled, you'll have to edit the html in-place. I use the firebug plugin in firefox to accomplish this.